# https security exception for amazon s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having two buckets https://almaconnect.dev.s3.amazonaws.com/ and https://almaconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/

The first one when I hit gives non-secure result and asks me to add an exception in the browser. The 2nd one works fine.
I am wondering what issue there can be.
Please, help me guys....

Thanks,
Amit Chaudhary

Comment: What is the name of the bucket you created for the first one [almaconnect.dev] ? Are you able to see the bucket in AWS S3 management console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server sends a wildcard certificate for `*.s3.amazon.com`.
This certifies all subdomains of the domain `s3.amazon.com`.

Certificate is valid for your working example `almaconnect.s3.amazon.com` but not for your second example `**alamonnect.**dev.s3.amazon.com`.

Create a bucket called e.g. `alaconnectdev` to work around this problem.

> With the distribution of Firefox 3.5, all major browsers allow only a single level of subdomain matching with certificate names that contain wildcards, in conformance with RFC 2818.
>
> In other words the certificate *.mydomain.com will work for one.mydomain.com or two.mydomain.com but NOT one.two.mydomain.com.

**Resources:**

- [Wikipedia Wildcard Certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate)
- [RFC 2818 on IETF.org](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt)